How do I perform pagination and sorting in a GraphQL query in AWS Amplify?
I am trying to develop a mobile application with Flutter and AWS Amplify and I am new on the Amplify. There is a real-time messaging part in the application. My problem is that when the user selects a conversation on the screen, he/she will be able to see the messages with that person on the new page and at the beginning I want to pull the last 10 messages from the database. Then, as I scroll up the screen, I want to call the previous messages from the database 10 by 10. But I could not find the necessary parameters to do this in the ModelQueries.list method and I cannot do it.
I designed the model for it in graphql.schema as follows:
type Message @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [read]}, {allow: owner}]) {
  id: ID!
  text: String!
  visualDatas: [String]!
  timestamp: AWSDateTime!
  conversationID: ID! @index(name: "byConversation")
  userID: ID! @index(name: "byUser")
}

type Conversation @model @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [create, read]}]) {
  id: ID!
  members: [String]!
  Messages: [Message] @hasMany(indexName: "byConversation", fields: ["id"])
}

I was able to do this with DataStore using the code, but I had to stop using DataStore due to some problems in the subscription method. And I'm currently trying to do it with the API, but I couldn't succeed.
DataStore code I used before:
Future<List<Message>> getMessages({
    required String conversationID,
  }) async {  
    final messages = await Amplify.DataStore.query(Message.classType,
        where: Message.CONVERSATIONID.eq(conversationID),
        sortBy: [
          const QuerySortBy(field: "createdAt", order: QuerySortOrder.ascending)
        ],
        pagination: const QueryPagination(page: 0, limit: 10));
    return messages;
  }

API code I am using now:
Future<PaginatedResult<Message>?> getMessages({
    required String conversationID,
  }) async {
    try {
      final request = ModelQueries.list(
        Message.classType,
        where: Message.CONVERSATIONID.eq(conversationID),
        limit: 10,
      );
      final response = await Amplify.API.query(request: request).response;
      final firstPageMessages = response.data;

      return firstPageMessages;
    } on ApiException catch (e) {
      safePrint('Query failed: $e');
    }
    return null;
  }

